# A word for extreme feeling sorry for someone?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes making a passionate expression of how sorry you feel for someone.

A bit like "sanctimonious" means making a big show of how moral you are.

Or "outrage" is a passionate display of anger or disapproval.

I'm looking for similar to express compassion or pity in an exaggerated or passionate way.

For example:
"as a display of his [extreme compassion] Bob wept when discussing the plight of the victims"

Comment: [feeling extremely sorry for someone=grammar]

Comment: *I pity the fool* - sure I heard that somewhere

Comment: A sincere but extreme expression, and an exaggerated and fake expression are two very different things. There are plenty of single-word terms for extreme or exaggerated expressions of emotions, but none afaik specifically for pity/compassion/sympathy.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest **commiseration**, which [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/commiseration) gives as

> **commiseration**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **1** Sympathy and sorrow for the misfortunes of others; compassion.

So the sentence could be

> As a display of his commiseration Bob wept when discussing the plight of the victims.

Comment: “Commiseration”? That’s feeble. If there isn’t a word in English, better not to pretend there is.  Sort of thing the Ancient Greeks and Romans went in for. Stiff upper lip here.

Answer (score -1):

If Bob wasn't weeping crocodile tears but was genuinely lachrymose, he was *empathizing* with the victims.

> **Empathy:** the action of understanding, being aware of, being sensitive to, and vicariously experiencing the feelings, thoughts, and experience of another of either the past or present without having the feelings, thoughts, and experience fully communicated in an objectively explicit manner
>
> also : the capacity for this

[[Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/empathy)]

Instead, if Bob was just showing false sympathy to the victims, he could be accused of *smarm*

> **Smarmy:** revealing or marked by a smug, ingratiating, or false earnestness

[[Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smarmy)]

*a tone of smarmy self-satisfaction*
— New Yorker

Comment: The word you appear to be thinking of is “sympathy”, not “empathy”. You might consult a dictionary to discover the difference. But I don’t think either is “extreme”.